# Problem with Booting

Tags: boot

I am using elementary os for more than 6 months now and i faced no problem, but now whenever i am trying to switch on my laptop the logo shows for few minutes and then it takes me to (initramfs) screen i tries several methods available online, none worked for me, it takes me to the new lvmetad error. Now every time i have to go to advanced booting option and select the older version to get my system started. Please help me with this issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you set the following it will always boot the version that currently works. However you may want to change it every time the kernel gets updated so as to always use the more recent version possible.

From terminal (Ctrl+T) execute:

```
sudo io.elementary.code /etc/default/grub
```

Set the line `GRUB_DEFAULT="0"` to `GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"`. Now close and execute on terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And done! On the next reboot it should work.